# Problems with WCF reliable session (reliable messaging)

Tags: wcf, ws-reliablemessaging

In our WCF application I am trying to configure reliable sessions.

Service:

```
 <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BindingStabiHTTP" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
             messageEncoding="Text">
       <reliableSession enabled="true" ordered="true" 
                        inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"/>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="0" maxStringContentLength="0" 
                        maxArrayLength="0" maxBytesPerRead="0"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="0" />
    </binding>
 </wsHttpBinding>
```

Client:

```
 <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BindingClientWsHttpStandard" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
             transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
             messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" 
             useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                     maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                     maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
       <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="true" />
       <security mode="Message">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                     realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                   negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                   algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
       </security>
    </binding>
```

Unfortunately I get an error which is as follows:
No signature message parts were specified for messages with the 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/CreateSequence' action.

If I disable the reliableSession on the client I get this message:
The action  is not supported by this endpoint. Only WS-ReliableMessaging February 2005 messages are processed by this endpoint.

So it seems that the server is configured correctly for RM.

I cannot find anything valuable about the error I get so I don't know how to fix this. Any ideas what can be wrong?

Thank in advance,

Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After starting a new test project that worked fine with RM I finally found the problem by comparing the configuration files. It appeared that our service configuration did not specify the correct binding configuration:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="somebehavior"
         name="somename">
   <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
             bindingConfiguration="SomeBinding"
             name="http" 
             contract="somecontract" />
   <endpoint address="mex" 
             binding="mexHttpBinding" 
             bindingConfiguration=""
             name="mex" 
             contract="IMetadataExchange" />
   <host>
      <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/somelibrary/someservice/" />
      </baseAddresses>
   </host>
</service>
```

This bindingConfiguration was empty. It then takes the default wsHttpBinding which is something different then the one specified (even if there is only 1).

Comment: I know these comments are frowned upon, but thank you thank you thank you! I've been beating my head agaist WCF timeouts for a few days now and this was the trick - my service config endpoint didn't have the bindingConfiguration set.  That was the trick and my timeouts are working perfect now.

Answer (score 2):

I think the security settings for client and server don't match.

The client has:

```
<security mode="Message">
   <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
               proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
   <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
             algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
</security>
```

and the server has nothing at all.....

Can you try to have the same settings for both client and server? Does it work then??

Comment: ah good point, unfortunately it did not make any difference and I still get the same error

Comment: See my own answer, finally found it.

In my test project it appears that by default the security settings for the server are not generated by default while the one on the client is. My test project ran fine in either case.